# MVC при билде не запускается IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

В решении находится 2 проекта :
WEB API и
ASP.NET MVC 5
при запуске WEb API все билдится и работает, при MVC открываться вкладка баузера и пишет что страница недоступна и в трее IIS показывает только WEB Api приложение.
Данная ошибка появилась после перезагрузки машины.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это пофиксить.

Comment: Я так понял, вам нужно запускать их одновременно? В настройках _решения_ задайте Multiple startup projects.

Comment: Я их запускаю раздельно после того как заводится API отдельно запуская MVC